# Expiración del token en Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8, tokens, passport

Estoy desarrollando una API en Laravel 8 y he implementado un login usando Passport. He estado investigando como cambiar la duración del token que se genera en el inicio de sesión del usuario y he visto hay gente que afirma que no se puede modificar, que siempre va a durar un año. De ser cierto, como podría controlar la duración del token? Ya que un año es un tiempo excesivo.

También he encontrado lo [siguiente](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#token-lifetimes):

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
 
    Passport::routes();
 
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15));
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
    Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMonths(6));
}
```

En el cual se establece la duración del token en 15 días, pero para comprobarlo me gustaría establecerlo en minutos, hay una función llamada `addMinutes` o parecido que funcione?

He probado a realizar lo siguiente en mi controlador:

```
Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(2));
Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(2));
Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(2));
```

Pero he probado a ver si a los dos minutos me cerraba la sesión y no ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, debes saber que `now()` ya es una instancia `Carbon`.

La definición de duración de **1 año** está definida en [esta línea](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/75fd509928952ccbaff47e609d4f0e657a2c22cf/src/Passport.php#L308) de código en la repo de Laravel Passport, puedes revisarla para familiarizarte con lo que estás usando:

```
return static::$tokensExpireIn ?? new DateInterval('P1Y');
```

El método estático que te ayudará aquí es el siguiente: `personalAccessTokensExpireIn()`

Lo que hace dicho método internamente es hacer un `diff`:

```
static::$personalAccessTokensExpireIn = Carbon::now()->diff($date);
```

Así que, solamente bastaría con utilizar lo siguiente:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
 
    Passport::routes();
 
    //Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15));
    //Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
    Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(1));
}
```

No uses todos los métodos, solamente usa el necesario, en tu caso es solamente el **personalAccessTokensExpireIn**.

He probado esto con un proyecto desde cero y está funcionando. Así que debe funcionarte a ti también. Para verificarlo simplemente vas a tu base de datos, a la tabla `oauth_access_tokens` y revisas la columna `expires_at` del usuario con el cual estés testeando.

Por otro lado, deberías considerar utilizar [Password Grant Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#password-grant-tokens).

Pero no tengo muy claro el motivo por el cual quieres modificar la duración del token, así que lo dejo a tu criterio.